# Explicit form for $\frac{\delta u^\alpha}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differentiation, variational-calculus

The title says it all: Is there a closed form expression for the following variational derivative,
$$
\frac{\delta u^\alpha}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}},
$$
where $u^\alpha$ is the four-velocity of a massive test particle moving through a spacetime with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$? Of course, one can use the normalization $u_\mu u^\mu = -1$ and derive $2u_\alpha \delta u^\alpha = u_\mu u_\nu \delta g^{\mu\nu}$, but this doesn't give $\delta u^\alpha/\delta g^{\mu\nu}$ by itself.

Comment: How does $u$ depend on $g$? This is like asking what is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $s$. The answer depends on how $f$ is a function of $s$. Using functional derivatives instead of regular derivatives won't change this.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, I don't know how $u$ depends on $g$, I suppose that's another way to phrase my question. $u$ surly does depend on $g$ since $u_{\alpha}\delta u^\alpha / \delta g^{\mu\nu}$ is in general nonzero.

Comment: So what kind of answer do you expect? Your question is akin to "what is $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm ds}$?". Would you be able to answer that? No, unless I tell you what $f=f(s)$ is. Your question is formally identical and, as such, unanswerable in its current form. (I hope this doesn't come off as harsh; I'm just trying to be frank).

Comment: I would understand $u$ as the 4-velocity of a point particle in a space-time characterized by $g$ as metric tensor. So $u$ solves the geodesic equation and thus implicitly depends on $g$, though it seems rather hard to make the dependency explicit.

Comment: $(\delta^\alpha_\mu u_\nu+\delta^\alpha_\nu u_\mu)/2$.

Comment: I updated the question. Hopefully it's clearer.